# Transferring files through mapped network drive - "Not enough space"

Tags: mapped-folder

We have a user who isn't able to transfer files from his C: drive to a SharePoint 2010 document library (through a Windows Explorer mapped network drive). He gets the following error message:

> There is not enough space on [http:...]. You need an additional [...] GB to copy these files.

When he checks the mapped drive Properties through the Windows Explorer interface, he gets the same used/free space/capacity numbers as when he checks his C: drive properties - in this case it says he has 206 MB free space left. We don't have a quota on the SharePoint site, I was able to paste 500+ MB of files into the document library.

Why is there that error message in Windows Explorer? Why does the Properties of the mapped network drive show the same numbers as the C: drive?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that a temp directory is first used before it is copied to SharePoint.  Does it do this with all files or just files beyond a certain size?

Comment: We didn't do such a test. We'll be trying to transfer our files in smaller batches.